# Is 2-dimensional nested dictionaries faster than several flattened dictionaries with an if statement in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to find a better plan to put the data in the dictionaries.
I will store my data in dictionaries in one python file (Call it "DB.py"). And import "DB.py" in another file to compute those data. (So there will be a lot of work around dictionary's keys and values). Because there are several dictionaries (around 5), **I don't know it's faster to nested into a 2d dictionary or put it flattened as 1d dictionaries and use if statement to choose which one to use in the computing program?** 
Choice One: `two_dimensional_dict = {1:{key:value, ...},2:{key:value}, ...}`

Choice Two:

```
one_dimensional_dict1 = {key:value, ...}
one_dimensional_dict2 = {key:value, ...}
...
```

In computing program, I will have a variable (call it "check") to lead the program which dictionary that they should find.

```
if check == 1:
     # Do work with one-dimensional_dict1
elif check == 2:
     # Do work with one-dimensional_dict2
...
```

So, I just wonder which one is faster? Any suggestions and idea will be really helpful!

Comment: "which one is faster?" - have you benchmarked the two approaches?

Comment: What is checker?

Comment: Since you don't know the exact number of dictionaries, your first choice is the one that best matches your data. Any difference in speed will be not worth having, because   the extra dictionary lookup to get to the second level will be negligible, especially when offset against 4 `if`-tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the time of a code snippet with timeit

db.py

```py
two_dimensional_dict = {1:{"key1": "value"},2:{"key2": "value"}}

one_dimensional_dict1 = {"key1": "value"}
one_dimensional_dict2 = {"key1": "value"}
```

```
>>> import timeit
>>> import db
>>> timeit.Timer('lambda :print(db.two_dimensional_dict[1]["key1"])').timeit()
0.06990942300035385
>>> timeit.Timer('lambda :print(db.one_dimensional_dict1["key1"])').timeit()
0.07525096900099015
```

For me two_dimensional_dict was faster but it may be different for you